# SQL CASE in WHERE Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

Good Afternoon
Im programming in SQL and i have this problem
The Code is:

```
    select 
    item.TX_Commercial_Family as 'Familia Comercial',
    sum(nota.NM_Invoice_Quantity) as 'Quantidade Faturada' ,
    sum(nota.NM_Material) as 'Valor Faturado' 
    from DW_DTS_Item item
    INNER JOIN DIS_DTS_Invoice_Fact nota ON item.SK_Item = nota.SK_Item
    inner join DW_DTS_Representative usuario on        nota.SK_Representative=usuario.SK_Representative
  inner join DW_DTS_Operation_Nature cfop on       cfop.SK_Operation_Nature=nota.SK_Operation_Nature
   where 
item.CD_Inventory_Group='30'
and (
    cfop.CD_CFOP='5101'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6101'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6107'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6108'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6109'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6113'
    OR cfop.CD_CFOP='6401'
    )
and( 
    case
        when :number = '01' then nota.SK_Representative='05' 
    end

)
and nota.SK_Currency='1'
and nota.CD_Country='BRASIL'
and nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-30'
--and extract (year from nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit) = extract(year from CURRENT_DATE)

group by item.TX_Commercial_Family,usuario.TX_Representative,usuario.SK_Representative
order by usuario.TX_Representative asc
```

But when I compile the code, the following error appears

```
SQL Error [102][S0001]:Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

The point is that I have to pass a parameter and through this parameter filter through which SK_Representative will appear in the code.

I've tried everything but the error continues to appear

Comment: Maybe more along the lines of: `(case when :number = '01' and nota.SK_Representative='05' then 1 else 0 end) = 1` which can be written as `:number = '01' and nota.SK_Representative='05'` directly. Also, what SQL dialect? `:variable` is not a MS SQL Server thing..

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The RDBMS is the MS SQL Server

Comment: In another code that i made this condition od :variable works fine, but in this code dont works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you are probably using SQL Server. 
Replace `:number` with `@number`.

e.g.

```
declare @number int = 1;
select  @number + 1;
set     @number = @number * 10;
select  @number;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use number as parameter then use '@' instead of ':' 
So use the following snippet where u are using case statements.

and( 
    case
        when @number = '01' then nota.SK_Representative='05' 
    end

)